# ReactJS dynamically call custom class

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

I am trying to setup a way to create form objects dynamically from some json values. Essentially, I have in my json the form object type and properties. I pass that type to a FormInput class that then calls the custom class containing the actual form object. My problem right now is that when I pass in the custom class name "TextInput" (this.props.formElementType) React just creates an element called 'textinput' instead of calling the class. It doesn't appear to like passing in a string, but wants just the classname. Essentially,...

```
TextInput = React.createClass({...})
...
FormItem = React.createElement(<TextInputPassedAsAString>, {...})
```

I am not sure if I can call a custom class this way or not, by passing a string. I need help with this implementation or a better idea as I am relatively new to React.

Below is all the relevant code starting with the children ending with the final render block. Please excuse the pseudo coffeescript.

TextInput

```
TextInput = React.createClass
  handleChange: (event)->
    this.setState
      value: event.target.value
  render: ->
    React.createElement('label', {
      value: this.props.formElementLabel
    })
    React.createElement('input', {
      id: this.props.formElementID,
      type: 'text'
    })
module.exports = TextInput
```

FormElement

```
FormElement = React.createClass
render: ->
  R.div(null,
    React.createElement(this.props.formElementType, {
      formElementID: this.props.formElementID,
      formElementLabel: this.props.formElementLabel
    })
module.exports = FormElement
```

The initial call/final render

```
React.createElement(FormElement, {
  formElementType: 'TextInput',
  formElementID: 'firstFormElement',
  formElementLabel: 'First text input'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the best way, easiest to reason about, etc. is probably to require `TextInput` in the module that's doing your final render. Create it there, passing in the other props to it, and then pass this created component to `FormElement` rather than passing the string representation of the component.

One way to do this more dynamically would be to have have a module that exports each dynamic component as a property/method on the export. Something like:

```
module.exports = {
  TextInput: ...
}
```

Then when you're rendering you could pass in something like this:

```
myImports[json.formElementType]
```

Comment: We ended up doing something very similar to your second suggestion. By the doing the requires in an object we could pass in a string to get the specific form element. String calls aren't fun but they will get the job done.